# Using PHP to generate random data

Tags: php

I am developing an application that has a question bank through which i want to generate a question paper randomly. I am using PHP and HTML. I am using html as my front end and for back end PHP. I have developed the code but there is a problem with it, its generating 4 textarea 2 for one question and i am unable to debug it

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "rgpv";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT ques FROM bank WHERE sub='$_POST[sub]' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


$result = $conn->query($sql);

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Form</title>

      <!-- Calling CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900|RobotoDraft:400,100,300,500,700,900'>

      <!--File for fonts-->
      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='css/bootstrap.css'>
      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='css/font-awesome.min.css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head> <!-- end Head -->

  <body background="images/journal.jpg">
    <!-- Mixins-->
      <!-- Form Title-->
    <div class="pen-title">
      <h1>University Institute of Technology- RGPV</h1><h2>Random Question Paper Generator Portal</h2>
</div>


       <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleTextarea">Question 1</label>
    <textarea class="form-control txt" id="name" rows="3" value="" disabled><?php echo $row["ques"]; ?></textarea>
  </fieldset>


       <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleTextarea">Question 2</label>
    <textarea class="form-control txt" id="name" rows="3" value="" disabled><?php echo $row["ques"]; ?></textarea>
  </fieldset>


    </body>
</html>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: you can randomly get the data from mysql. If you want to use PHP for random then try rand function.

Comment: Would you like us to write it for you or guess?

Comment: Well..Buddy you want something like ready made bread for your breakfast???

Comment: No actually i was working on it. I asked this because while searching i came up with many algo and i got confused how to implement it. As i am new with this. Well for now the code is added please tell me why this is acting like this

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function get_question()
{

  // Connect to your database storing your questions
  $connection = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database");

  if($connection->connect_errno)
  {
    die("Error connecting to database.");
  }

  // Load all your questions from your database into an array
  $query = "SELECT * FROM questions";
  $result = $connection->query($query);
  $questions = $result->fetch_all();

  // Randomly select a question from your array to output
  $number = rand(0, count($questions) - 1);
  return $questions[$number];
}

$question = get_question();

// Use var_dump() to view the raw output from your database
// You can now output your question and format it however you'd like
var_dump($question);

// You can call this function as many times as you'd like using a loop
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $question = get_question();
    // Output your question properly formatted here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like this & pull data from your db :

when ever you call it like : `UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(0,25,5)`

You will get an array `$quantity` of jumbled numbers between `$min` to `$max`.

From the backend just pull questions in the array order.